# Searching for a Binary Value

Tags: c++, sockets, search, binary

I am trying to find a way to identify the start of a chunk of data sent via a TCP socket. The data chunk has the value of the integer 1192 written into it as the first four bytes, followed by the content length. How can I search the binary data (the char* received) for this value? I realize I can loop through and advance the pointer by one each time, copy out the first four bytes, and check it, but that isn't the most elegant or possibly efficient solution.

Is there also another way this could be done that I'm not thinking of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the `memmem` function that could help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like linear scanning *might* be required, but you shouldn't really be losing your message positioning if the sending side of the connection is making its `send()`/`write()` calls in a sensible manner, you are reading in your buffers properly, and there isn't an indeterminate amount of "dead" space in the stream between messages.

If the protocol itself is sensible (there is at least a length field!), you should never lose track of message boundaries. Just read the marker/length pair, then read `length` payload bytes, and the next message should start immediately after this, so a linear scan shouldn't have to go *anywhere* ideally.

Also, don't bother copying explicitly, just cast:

```
// call htonl() to flip endianness if need be...
uint32_t x = *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(charptr);
```